# wc with find. error if space in folders name

Tags: linux, bash, directory, size, space

I need to calculate folder size in bytes.
if folder name contains space **/folder/with spaces/** then following command not work properly

```
wc -c `find /folder -type f` | grep total | awk '{print $1}'
```

with error

```
wc: /folder/with: No such file or directory
wc: spaces/file2: No such file or directory
```

How can it done?

Comment: Note that, on Linux/BSD/Unix, they are "directories" and not the Windows-ism of "folders" which is a user term and not the same thing.

Comment: If find's output fits into a single argv buffer, why not just `find /folder -type f -exec wc -c {} +`?

Comment: Reading all files with `wc` is time consuming. Use this one-liner instead: `{ find "/path/to/directory" -type f -printf "%s+"; echo 0; } | bc`

Answer (score 2):

Try this line instead:

```
find /folder -type f | xargs -I{} wc -c "{}" | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: you example calculates size of each file separately

Comment: Sorry, thought that's what you were looking for.
You can get the sum using this line:

find /folder -type f | xargs -I{} wc -c "{}" | awk '{print $1}' | paste -sd+ - | bc


 (there might be a limit to the amount of files that can be processed this way)

Answer (score 1):

You need the names individually quoted.

```
$: while read n;                     # assign whole row read to $n
   do a+=("$n");                     # add quoted "$n" to array
   done < <( find /folder -type f )  # reads find as a stream
$: wc -c "${a[@]}" |                 # pass wc the quoted names 
     sed -n '${ s/ .*//; p; }'       # ignore all but total, scrub and print
```

Compressed to short couple lines -

```
$: while read n; do a+=( "$n"); done < <( find /folder -type f )
$: wc -c "${a[@]}" | sed -n '${ s/ .*//; p; }'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because bash (different to zsh) word-splits the result of the command substitution. You could use an array to collect the file names:

```
files=()
for entry in *
do
  [[ -f $entry ]] && files+=("$entry")
done
wc -c "${files[@]}" | grep .....
```